# How do we recognize the character drawn on my iPhone screen?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uigesturerecognizer

I Write Code for Gesture Recognition. In that Code i used 
touchsBegan ,touchesMoved, touchesEnd Methods. It shows the Shape what i draw on my iPhone Screen.
Now my Task is I want to Recognize the Character Which is Drawn on the screen.

for example if i Draw "A". after some particular timeout my Alertview will be able to Display that Character.
is there any APIs available for Character Recognition?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there's no Cocoa Touch API to detect characters that has been drawed on the screen. You'll have t find a 3rd party library that does it or implement your own.

Comment: is Apple Allows to Use 3rd Party APIs?

Comment: Yes, as long as they don't use any private apple API

Comment: Can u please provide me a 3rd Party API Link.

Comment: Google it, compare all of them and choose the one that suits you

Comment: What about Tesseract OCR?

Comment: I've used that in the past and works fine, but I've used to recognize characters from a picture. If it works in the way you want it, go for it.

Comment: I Want to implement $1 and $N Recognizer. How do i implement them ? Can u Please give me some initial steps and also if possible give me some links.

Comment: @Suresh did you find any solution ? i am on the same task now. plz share your experience.Thanx in advance.

Comment: @PeacefulWarrior No We didn't find solution.i think this is too complex. We kept this task aside. Now we r doing another application. Please Refer [this](http://britg.com/2011/06/17/complex-gesture-recognition-in-ios-part-2-the-ios-implementation/) link it may be useful for u.

Comment: @iSuresh did you find the solution?? because i am also in same problem .. need help ..